# Unable to boot Ubuntu 16.04 on MacBook Air

Tags: boot, 16.04, secure-boot

I have been using Ubuntu for a while now on my MacBook Air, and everything has worked fine, until today, when my battery drained and I was unable to boot afterwards.

About 30 minutes after turning on my computer, and after the Plymouth logo was shown, the initramfs shell appeared, and I got an error message saying something like "No partition with UUID xxxxxxx-xxxxx...". After this I tried to run `blkid` and it gave me UUIDs for /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda3, which are an EFI partition and a swap partition, respectively, but it did not give a UUID for /dev/sda2 where my Ubuntu installation is. However I was given several lines of error messages. The first one was

`ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0`

and the last ones were

`blk_update_request: I/O error, den sda, sector 1050630
Buffer: I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 0, async page read`.

This is the entire output of `blkid`: [image: .]

So I figured the hard drive probably was corrupted, and I tried to boot from a Live USB, but got an error like "File /boot does not exist". This is strange, since I have booted with that exact USB on this exact laptop, but I don't know if this is related to the problem.

What is causing this problem, and what can I do to fix it? I would be extremely grateful for any help at all!

**Update:** Using the `dd` command to write from `/dev/sda2` to `/dev/null` I have found out that the bytes 0 to 23 on sda2 are the ones I am unable to read from. Is it safe to replace these bytes with zeros?

**Update 2:** I tried using `dd` to overwrite the defective parts of the hard drive, but got the same error as when I tried to read from them or do `blkid`

**Update 3:** I was able to boot from the Live USB despite the error saying `/boot` could not be found, I just had to wait a minute or so. I was able to launch GParted, but got a lot of error messages, and GParted was not even able to get the file system type of `sda2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to fix my problem was to reinstall Ubuntu.

What I did was to boot from a Live USB, then I had to overwrite the defective part of the disk with zeros by doing

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2 count=24 bs=1024
```

Except I accidentally typed `bs=1m` instead of `bs=1024` so I deleted more data than I intended. If I hadn't done this, maybe I wouldn't have had to reinstall Ubuntu.

Anyway, after the `dd` command, the installer program worked as intended and Ubuntu installed successfully. I lost all my data, but at least the laptop still works.